# Why does (display: flex) behave like an inherited property?

Tags: html, css, display

I have a question about display property. So, why can we establish `{display: flex}` for div, and this value will be given to all `p`, what belong to div. It's got me thinking that {display: flex} is inherited property. Am I right?
But I don't understand. The same thing have no effect, when we establish {display: inline} for div. Because this property establishes only for `p`. Please, explain me.

```
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  display: inline;
}
```

This is my code:
https://codepen.io/Eva255/pen/OJMNpBe

Comment: the default direction when using display:flex is row so you will have all the p *inline*. It has nothing to do with inherit

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to well researched. please research on a topic before asking a question on it. Everything needs to have a default behaviour and that default behaviour for ````flex-direction```` is ````row````.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you've noticed that `display:flex` changes the items from a row into a column. Why is that so?

`display:flex` tells the browser that you want the items in your `div` to be arranged using the **flexbox** layout.

The flexbox layout was designed specifically for developers that wanted **flex**ible **box**es on a single row or single column, evenly spaced out. Hence, when you give `div` a `display:flex`, it arranges the div's `p`s in a single row, rather than the default column.

That's it. Nothing about the p's themselves have changed per se.

More reading for you: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ (Click the background section, don't just gloat at the pictures, I know they're pretty)

Hope it helps!